# Android 4.4.2 fully working my App but other versions not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My app is working properly android 4.4.2. But when I install a other version of the application and try to capture an image then the app will crash.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private String encoded_string, image_name,getUnitCode,getEmpNo,ImageDate,ImageTime;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private File file;
    private Uri file_uri;
    EditText unitCode,empNo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check KJPhotoAudit Folder Available
        checkMyDirectory();
    }

    public void CaptureImage(View view){
        unitCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.unitCode);
        getUnitCode = unitCode.getText().toString().toUpperCase();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getUnitCode)) {
            unitCode.setError("Unit Code is Empty");
            return;
        }

        empNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.empNo);
        getEmpNo = empNo.getText().toString().toUpperCase();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getEmpNo)) {
            empNo.setError("Employee Number is Empty");
            return;
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        getFileUri();

        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,file_uri);
        startActivityForResult(i,10);
    }

    private void getFileUri(){
        //set date to string
        ImageDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format( new Date());
        ImageTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format( new Date());

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format( new Date());
        image_name = "MY_" +"JPEG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg" ;

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/Myfolder") + File.separator + image_name);

        file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)   {
        if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            new Encode_image().execute();
        }
    }

    private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids){

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,20,stream);

            byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
            encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array,0);
            bitmap.recycle();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){
            makeRequest();
        }
    }

    private void makeRequest() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http:/www.myweb.com/connection.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                System.out.println("response"+response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("error"+error);
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("encoded_string",encoded_string);
                map.put("image_name",image_name);
                map.put("unit_code",getUnitCode);
                map.put("emp_no",getEmpNo);
                map.put("image_date",ImageDate);
                map.put("image_time",ImageTime);
                return map;
            }
        };    

        System.out.println("req ="+request);
        requestQueue.add(request);

        ResetEmpNumber();
    }

    public void checkMyDirectory(){

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Myfolder");
        if(!dir.exists() && !dir.isDirectory()) {
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Myfoldert");
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    public void ResetEmpNumber(){
        //Reset Employee Text Field
        empNo.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: On what API level did you try to run your app?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @476rick Api level 19.  this my build gradle  `code` android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mad.madusanka.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    } `code`

Comment: @476rick myapp can capture image and then press ok.app will unfortunately stopped working error.

Comment: Can you include the error in your question?

Comment: @476rick unfortunately myapp has stopped working. this is my error.:(

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174/4585226

Comment: We need to see the StackTrace of the code. Then we can help you solve this.

Comment: Or you need to provide a sample project, then I can try to fix it.